# insert into mysql in ionic

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am building an ionic app and i am having problem inserting to database. i have been trying it in different ways and it is still not working . when i click submit noting goes to the database. i need help or you can suggest another method. just one filed i want to insert "name".

my php script

```
<?php

  $data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
   $name =mysql_real_escape_string($data->name);    
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("ang");
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO lit(`name`) VALUES ('".$name."')");
?>
```

my controller.js

```
var app=angular.module('app.controllers', []);

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function() {


app.controller('signupCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.up = function() {
$http.post("http://localhost/angl/add.php",{'name':$scope.name})
  .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    console.log("data entered");
})
    }
})
```

my html file

```
<ion-view title="Buy Insurance">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
        <h4>Personal Information</h4>
        <form class="list">
                <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Insured name">

            <input type="button" value="submit" class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="up()"> 
        </form>

        <ion-list></ion-list>


    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Have you got any log to show us? Like for example, does the database *says* something when you try to insert. Are you sure your php script is even executed at all?

Comment: yes it work wit normal html .do you know any other way

Comment: Do you have any errors from the javascript/angular side? without more information, log files for example, it is difficult to help you more. Like are you testing your app from the browser, emulator, device? we need more context